# Junit5 Suite did not discover any tests (spring boot with cucumber setup)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, cucumber, junit5

Following
[this example](https://github.com/datmt/Spring-tutorial/blob/main/spring-boot-cucumber-junit5-testcontainers/pom.xml), I'm trying to run a cucumber test in JUnit5, but the @Suite doesn't like me:

```
org.junit.platform.suite.engine.NoTestsDiscoveredException: Suite [org.ono.sprint.demo.CucumberRunnerTest] did not discover any tests
```

and I have fiddled with it and researched this for a the better part of a day now, would be extremely thankful if someone can give me hint in the right direction. It seems to be a problem on the a JUnit level since it doesn't even recognize the test class.

The test setup has an empty `@Suite`, `@SpringBootTest` class which appears to be configured by cucumber-specific annotations ...

```
package org.ono.sprint.demo;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "org.ono.sprint.demo")
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

...to do the actual test described in a cucumber step definitions class, which is accompanied by a feature file. I don't think this is a cucumber problem at this stage, so I am ommitting the feature file):

```
package org.ono.sprint.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;

import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinitionsTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  @When("I request a greeting")
  public void i_request_a_greeting() {
    String greetingUrl = "http://localhost:" + port + "/greetings";

    String greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(greetingUrl, String.class);
    Assertions.assertEquals("Hello", greeting);
  }

}
```

also, the actual spring boot implementation is most trivial, so ommitted.

These are the maven dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <junit-platform.version>1.9.1</junit-platform.version>
    <cucumber.version>7.10.1</cucumber.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-console-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

and I am using the `<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId`>.

Comment: `@SelectClasspathResource("features")` suggests that the features are located in `src/test/resources/features`. Are they?

Comment: Yes, the feature file is  src/test/resources/features/greeting.feature. 

There also is a src/test/resources/cucumber.properties file with this line in it: cucumber.publish.quiet=false 

But it seems to me that the whole cucumber mechanism doesn't even start, since the Suite doesn't seem to take notice of the CucumberRunnerTest (I assume that is the launching point for the cucumber magic).

Comment: Okay. I can't tell you what is wrong. It looks like you are missing the `junit-platform-suite` (not -api) dependency but the error message suggests otherwise.

Comment: Maybe start with https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton. If anything the depencies are more cleanly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, following M.P.Korstanjes advice, I got it to work. Most grateful, Thanks ! I believe it was a mix between lacking the `junit-platform-suite` dependency and, most importantly a wrong folder structure: this stuff expects to find the package folders under `src/test/java` to exactly replicate what is under `src/main/java`. Looks like the `@SelectClassPathResource` annotation did not work and falls back to default behavior. Also, the gherkin feature files apparently need to be under `src/test/resources` again, replicating the package folder structure from there. All this was not the case.
So my sprint now looks like so:

```
src/
  main/
    java/
      org/
        ono/
          sprint/
             demo/
               DemoApplication.java
               HomeController.java
  test/
    java/
      org/
        ono/
          sprint/
             demo/
               SmokeTest.java
               CucumberRunnerTest.java
    resource/
      org/
        ono/
          sprint/
             demo/
               helloworld.feature
```

and the `CucumberRunnerTest` like so:

```java
package org.ono.sprint.demo;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "org.ono.sprint.demo")
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

The dependencies are as follows. Note the dependency management section that was needed to resolve some of the cucumber deps.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.10.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.14.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>7.14.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```